# Error while loading the data to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to execute the command mentioned on the tensorflow website:
`df_train = pd.read_csv(train_file, names=COLUMNS, skipinitialspace=True)`

I am getting the below error message.

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 210, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'tuple'>
```

Can some please help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: What is `train_file`... Doesn't look like the file location is valid.

Comment: Do you have a trailing coma after your definition of `train_file`? E.g. `train_file='some_file',`

Comment: I am trying to execute the codes shown in the below link https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide . Train file is loaded into a temporary location. But when I read that into Pandas it is failing. Is there anything that I am doing wrong. I am pretty new to python scripting.Thanks in advance for helping on this.